# How to display two values serially with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I am straggling some time with jq to parse json file. I have to grab ID and Name in the same line so I can do some logic after.

```
{
"elements": [{
        "id": "e20a9cd8-8683-4986-b6c0-e5fbf51cbf7f",
        "name": "Mike",
        "components": [{
            "id": "15f959fc-6d2d-451a-a59e-430a05a1852c",
            "pid": "ZZZ1"
        }],
        "tenantIds": null,
        "productIds": null
    },
    {
        "id": "d892f2eb-d7f3-49f8-9176-2113351cccf8",
        "name": "Steve",
        "components": [{
            "id": "0c44c917-e0e5-4fa3-b87c-89f9ac0815b4",
            "pid": "XXX3"
        }],
        "tenantIds": null,
        "productIds": null
    }
]
```

}

With `jq '{elements}[] | .[].id` I am getting ID's but I can't find solution how to add appropriate name beside ID. I tried something like

```
{elements}[] | .[].id + " " + .[].name
```

and

```
{elements}[] | .[].id + .[].name
```

but it's not what I expected.

I want to get:

```
15f959fc-6d2d-451a-a59e-430a05a1852c Mike
d892f2eb-d7f3-49f8-9176-2113351cccf8 Steve
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply string concatenation:

```
jq '.elements[] | .id +" "+ .name' file
```

The output:

```
"e20a9cd8-8683-4986-b6c0-e5fbf51cbf7f Mike"
"d892f2eb-d7f3-49f8-9176-2113351cccf8 Steve"
```

---

To output without double quotes use `-r` (`--raw-output`) option:

```
jq '.elements[] | .id +" "+ .name' -r file
e20a9cd8-8683-4986-b6c0-e5fbf51cbf7f Mike
d892f2eb-d7f3-49f8-9176-2113351cccf8 Steve
```

Comment: Perfect, that's it. Thanks!